# Ubuntu default terminal in Lubuntu

Tags: command-line, lubuntu

Recently I had to re-install my linux OS, and now I ran into some annoying problems.

I had Ubuntu, and then I installed the Lubuntu desktop enviroment. I do not like LXTerminal but I was able to use the default Ubuntu terminal in Lubuntu.

Since the new instalation, both Ubun. and Lubun., I have not been able to start the Ubun. terminal in the Lubun. desktop enviroment. I can start LXterminal, and I see that the Ubuntu default terminal is installed, but I can not find it // start it while im in the Lubuntu environment.

I was wondering where the terminal is and how can I get it into to show up in the Accessories. I really really dislike LXterminal :(

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

If by "Ubuntu default terminal" you mean the Gnome Terminal, it should be located at `/usr/bin/gnome-terminal`.

You can try launching it by pressing <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and entering `gnome-terminal`.